# How could I fix this Auto Increment?

Tags: php, pdo, auto-increment, steam-web-api

So, here is my problem on login through steam id it creates an account on my website but it also decides on next login to skip an Auto Increment causing the next registered member to gain a ton of Auto Incremented member id's

[image: Database layout]

```
<?php
require ("common.php");

class SteamSignIn
{
const STEAM_LOGIN = 'https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login';

public static function genUrl($returnTo = false, $useAmp = true)
{
    $returnTo = (!$returnTo) ? (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') .  '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] : $returnTo;

    $params = array(
        'openid.ns'         => 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0',
        'openid.mode'       => 'checkid_setup',
        'openid.return_to'  => $returnTo,
        'openid.realm'      => (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
        'openid.identity'   => 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select',
        'openid.claimed_id' => 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select',
    );

    $sep = ($useAmp) ? '&amp;' : '&';
    return self::STEAM_LOGIN . '?' . http_build_query($params, '', $sep);
}

public static function validate()
{
    $params = array(
        'openid.assoc_handle'   => $_GET['openid_assoc_handle'],
        'openid.signed'         => $_GET['openid_signed'],
        'openid.sig'            => $_GET['openid_sig'],
        'openid.ns'             => 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0',
    );

    $signed = explode(',', $_GET['openid_signed']);
    foreach($signed as $item)
    {
        $val = $_GET['openid_' . str_replace('.', '_', $item)];
        $params['openid.' . $item] = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($val) : $val; 
    }

    $params['openid.mode'] = 'check_authentication';

    $data =  http_build_query($params);
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 
                "Accept-language: en\r\n".
                "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
                "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
            'content' => $data,
        ),
    ));

    $result = file_get_contents(self::STEAM_LOGIN, false, $context);


    preg_match("#^http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/([0-9]{17,25})#", $_GET['openid_claimed_id'], $matches);
    $steamID64 = is_numeric($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : 0;

    return preg_match("#is_valid\s*:\s*true#i", $result) == 1 ? $steamID64 : '';
}
}

$steam_login_verify = SteamSignIn::validate();
if(!empty($steam_login_verify))
{
// Grab Data From Steam API
    $json = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=' .  $sapik . '&steamids='. $steam_login_verify .'&format=json');
//Decode Data From Steam API
    $data = json_decode($json);
foreach($data->response->players as $player)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO steam (steamid, personaname, profileurl, avatar, avatarmedium, avatarfull ) VALUES ( :steamid, :personaname, :profileurl, :avatar,   :avatarmedium, :avatarfull) "; 
    $query_params = array( 
        ':steamid' => $player->steamid, 
        ':personaname' => $player->personaname, 
        ':profileurl' => $player->profileurl, 
        ':avatar' => $player->avatar, 
        ':avatarmedium' => $player->avatarmedium, 
        ':avatarfull' => $player->avatarfull, 
        );

}

                try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
    switch( $ex->errorInfo[1] )
 {
     case 1062:
        $ps = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `steam` WHERE steamid = :sid");
        $ps->bindParam(':sid', $steam_login_verify);
        $ps->execute();
        $ps->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($ps as $row)
            {
                $_SESSION['sid'] = $row['steamid'];
            }

            header('Location:'.$basedir);
            die('redirecting to'.$basedir);
        ;

}
    }
    $ps = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `steam` WHERE steamid = :sid");
    $ps->bindParam(':sid', $steam_login_verify);
    $ps->execute();
    $ps->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($ps as $row)
    {
        $_SESSION['sid'] = $row['steamid'];
    }

    header('Location:'.$basedir);
    die('redirecting to'.$basedir);
} else { 

$steam_sign_in_url = SteamSignIn::genUrl();
}
```

Comment: keep the reference in session and check it before inserting into the database

Comment: @Sundar not quite sure what you mean there.

Comment: Why does it matter if you are skipping auto increment ids? Alternatively, why do you need the ID? Both the steam ID from the API call to `GetPlayerSummaries` and the ID returned from Valve after the open id signin are unique.